# Hyperledger Fabric: Unable to Invoke using Node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am having an issue in the Hyperledger fabric Node SDK.

Network Details:

1. The network consists of 4 organisations each deployed on different Kubernetes cluster.
2. Each organisation has 2 peers which joined a single channel say mychannel.
3. Each organisation has 1 CA running.
4. Ordering service is Raft.
5. CouchDB is used as statedb.
6. The invokes from the CLI are also working fine and the data is being synced between all the 8 peers.
7. Hypelredger explorer is up and running with the one organisation details and is able to list all the other 6 peers in the dashboard.

Now back to issue, I tried to deploy the Node.js SDK for Org1.
I created a connection profile having the details of the Org1 Peers, Orderer and CA.

The users are enrolled (Admin and user1).

Now when I try to invoke transaction there are two cases:

1. Service discovery enabled: In this case, the SDK tries to communicate with the other peers in the network and creator org peers but all returns the context deadline exceed error.
2. Service discovery disabled: Invokes successful.

I have no idea why the invoke transactions are failed when the service discovery is enabled.

Comment: Can you add your core.yaml/docker compose file? Would help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Actually it is deployed on 4 Kubernetes clusters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue is resolved when I added the host aliases into my /etc/hosts file.

I need to add the host names and IP for each peer in the /etc/hosts files.

After adding the host names, the SDK started working.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Could be your anchor peers are configured incorrectly, since discovery reports those, and some clients will use them.

Comment: Yeah anchor peers are defined correctly, because the data is being synced between the peers.

Comment: And the hyperledger explorer is up and is able to detect the other peers in the network

Comment: That only means that peers from inside k8s can see other peers. The anchors have to resolve correctly when being tried to resolve from outside k8s. It is very difficult to get k8s to work correctly here, since the DNS design is fundamentally broken in it.

Comment: Can explorer see peers across clusters, or from outside a cluster?

Comment: Yeah, it is being able to detect each and every single peer in the network

Comment: have you configured  CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT because service discovery requires this env variable

Comment: yeah it is configured